# Issues when converting bytes to integers (Java specific?)

Tags: java, binary

I'm a bit confused regarding a conversion from bytes to integers. Consider the following code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0, (byte) 0xF0 };

int masked = data[0] << 8 & 0xFF | data[1] & 0xFF; //240
int notMasked = data[0] << 8 | data[1]; //-16
```

Because bytes in java are signed, `data[1]` is not 240 decimal, but rather the 2's complement, -16. However, it should still be, in binary: `0x11110000` so, why do I need to do `data[1] & 0xFF` ?

Is Java converting everything to Integer before passing it to the `|` operator? Why does `&0xFF` make a difference then?

Comment: I did a C to Java port of some code a while ago that used a lot of bitwise operations and came up with a [helper class](https://github.com/pillingworthz/level9j/blob/master/src/java/uk/co/threeonefour/l9/vm/Conv.java) to make things a bit easier. No guarantees as to the quality or efficiency of these but they did the job for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java bytes are signed (unfortunately) - so when you promote the value to an `int` in order to perform the bitwise `|`, it ends up being sign-extended as `0xFFFFFFF0`. That then messes up the `|` with `data[0]`. The masking with `& 0xff` converts it to an integer value of 240 (just `0x000000F0`) instead.

However, you've stlil got a problem. This code:

```
int masked = data[0] << 8 & 0xFF | data[1] & 0xFF;
```

should be:

```
int masked = ((data[0] & 0xff) << 8) | (data[1] & 0xFF);
```

... otherwise you're masking *after* the shift, which won't work. I've added brackets because I'm never sure of the predence of `&`, `<<` and `|`...

Comment: Aha! So both `|` and `&` promote to integer, so `&0xFF` happens *over the integer value*. That fully explains it, thanks so much!

Comment: @Miquel: `& 0xFF` does the promotion to `int`, so `|` doesn't have to, if you see what I mean :)

Comment: Follow-up: this is of course Java specific, but do other languages do the same?

Comment: Yeap. Nice gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @Miquel: I don't know about all languages. In C# for example, `byte` is unsigned so the issue doesn't arise. See my edit though - your code still has a problem, I think.

Comment: Saw your edit, thanks! You're absolutely right. I messed it up when typing the example, but now that you've pointed it out, I can't silently edit it ;) Good reference for future visitors, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to a known "puzzle"

```
byte x = -1;
x = x >>>= 1;
System.out.println(x);
```

produces

```
-1
```

No shift? This is because before compiling arithemtic / shift / comparison expressions javac promotes byte (as well as short and char) to int or to long (if there is any long in the expression), so it works as follows

```
x -> int = 0xFFFFFFFF; 0xFFFFFFF >>> 1 = 0x7FFFFFF; (byte)0x7FFFFFF -> 0xFF
```

Comment: Nice :) But just so no one gets confused: you're playing with the signed shift operator here (`>>>`) instead of the normal one (`>>`)

Comment: well, i think >>> is called unsigned, otherwise there's no puzzle, is it?